# Как зайти на страничку с машины с локальной сети?

Tags: веб-сервер, tomcat

На `localhost:8080/MVC/` заходит. На `мой_ip_подсети:8080/MVC/` с моей машины заходит. С другой машины, подключенной к тому же роутеру не заходит, хотя и отвечает на `ping`. Сервер на `Apache Tomcat 7.0`. Как быть?

P.S.: С локалкой работать, к сожалению, пока не приходилось.

Comment: Попробуйте перезапустить Apache перенастроив его c localhost на IPv4

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что нужно было просто [создать правило в брандмауэре для входящих подключений порта](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44238923/11488556).